# Gmail not receiving mails sent by Swiftmailer via sendmail

Tags: php, gmail, sendmail, swiftmailer

Ok I have a code to send emails. I'm using **Swiftmailer** and the transporter is **sendmail**. Here is the main code:

```
$transport = \Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i');
$message   = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Notificatio')
            ->setFrom(array(BR_EMAIL => 'BR'))
            ->setTo(array($user->getEmail() => $user->getFirstName().' '.$user->getLastName()))
            ->setBody($msg, 'text/html', 'utf-8');

$headers = $message->getHeaders();
$headers->addIdHeader('Message-ID', time().'.'.uniqid('noreply').'@'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$headers->addTextHeader('X-Mailer', 'PHP v'.phpversion());

if(!$mailer->send($message, $failures)) {
    echo "Failures:";
    print_r($failures);
}
```

Now here is the strange part. If the recipient is a Gmail user, the email never gets to it. The `send` method doesn't give any failures, but the email is lost. It's not in the spam folder either.
**But** when the recipient is a Gmail Business user (email from Gmail engine with custom domain) the emails are received perfectly and into inbox.

So what is the problem? Is it Gmail filtering the mails? Or do I need to add other Headers?

**EDIT**
Don't know how, but the problem is resolved.

Comment: is your firewall is not allowing ?

Comment: what firewall??? I said that I receive emails to Gmail Business user. The problem is with Gmail...

Comment: Check your `/var/log/mail.log` You can see the status of your mail (and whether it has been accepted by Gmail).

Comment: I have the same problem. It used to work, now any gmail addresses do not receive my email.